# Cannot compile SQLite application in XE3

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe3, firedac

When trying to use an SQLite connection in a Win32 project on XE3 using
version 8.0.5.3365 of FireDAC I'm getting the following error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] uADPhysSQLiteCli.pas(992): F2051 Unit
>   uADStanCipher was compiled with a different version of
>   uADStanUtil.ADFreeAndNil

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Have you downloaded the modified `uADStanCipher` unit before you installed version 8.0.5.3365 ? There was a standalone hotfix for this unit as far as I remember and maybe the IS installer didn't overwrite that version of this unit.

Comment: The unit is not available in the clean installation of firedac, only a dcu.  Also, the standalone hotfix, AFAIK, was only for 64 bit, not for  32 bit compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ADGUIxWaitCursor1 on your form.